# EasyMock.expect() throwing null pointer

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, powermock, easymock

I am using PowerMock and EasyMock in my project. I am getting null pointer exception while calling the Easymock.expect() method call.

JUnit class:

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.*;
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({InfoDao.class})
public class AdminUtilTest {

//mocking interface 
@Mock
InfoDao infoDaoMock;

@Test
    public void testSetUp() {
        assertNotNull(infoDaoMock);
    }
@Test
    public void initInfoTest() throws Exception {

  // getting null pointer exception in this line..         
         expect(infoDaoMock.getGroupInfoById(isA(Long.class))).andReturn("testString");

         replay(infoDaoMock);
        /*rest of the code*/
    }
}
```

The testSetUp is not null and the `assertNotNull` is success.

I also tried:

```
InfoDao infoDaoMock = createMock(InfoDaoMockImpl.class);
```

This is also throwing `NullPointerException`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the code working. The issue was with Long.class. I manually gave some sample long value and mock object is getting loaded.

`expect(infoDaoMock.getGroupInfoById(123456L)).andReturn("testString");`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong imports

You need

```
import org.powermock.api.easymock.annotation.Mock;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.replay;
```

Comment: The mock object is of `EasyMock` and thats why i am using `EasyMock.reply(...)`